# How to configure two Dell U2415's monitors daisy chained over displayport with Nvidia Titan X

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, displayport

I am working on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS desktop with the default gnome desktop. I installed the nvidia proprietary driver nvidia-driver-390 from Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers.

When the desktop starts, it only shows on the primary monitor. I have to run

```
xset dpms force off
```

to force the monitors into sleep state and then move the mouse to wake them up and both monitors become active. However, one of the monitors runs at a very low resolution (640x480) while the other runs at the full resolution (1920x1200). Here's a screenshot of the Nvidia X Settings.
[Nvidia X settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyQpH.png)

The first monitor is detected as "NVIDIA" with resolution 640x480 (the only options under resolution are Off, Auto, and 640x480). The second monitor is correctly detected as "DELL U2415" with resolution 1920x1200. Here is the output of the xrandr command. DP-0.8 is the first monitor in the daisy chain and DP-0.1 is the second. I have enabled displayport 1.2 on the first monitor and disabled on the 2nd monitor.

```
    Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1200, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0.1 connected 1920x1200+640+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+  59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-0.8 connected primary 640x480+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   640x480       59.94*+
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0.1.8 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

At this point, there was no /etc/X11/xorg.conf file or monitors.xml file anywhere on the machine. I saved the X configuration file from Nvidia X Settings application. The saved /etc/X11/xorg.conf file is as follows.

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 390.77  (buildd@lcy01-amd64-022)  Thu Sep  6 07:51:39 UTC 2018

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "NVIDIA"
    HorizSync       31.5 - 31.5
    VertRefresh     60.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX TITAN X"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-2.8"
    Option         "metamodes" "DP-0.8: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, DP-0.1: nvidia-auto-select +640+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I see only one "monitor" section in this xorg.config. Why doesn't it list the 2nd monitor?

In any case, how can I have the nvidia card properly detect both monitors as Dell U2415 along with the 1920x1200 resolution?

Comment: This same daisy-chained displayport monitor setup works fine with Windows 10. Both monitors are identical except the 1st one has displayport 1.2 (MST) enabled and the 2nd has it disabled. I can't figure out why the nvidia driver is detecting the 1st monitor as NVIDIA with very low resolution and the 2nd monitor as DELL 2415 with the correct resolution - 1920x1200.

Comment: It may not be related but you're using a driver version older than your graphics card. Nvidia recommends 430 or newer only.

Comment: Thanks. I tried Nvidia 430 driver from apt repository ppa:graphics-drivers. But it causes the high resolution display (2nd display) to flicker badly. And the 1st display still shows 640x480 fixed resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Displays settings in the settings panel.

Starting the nvidia server settings resets all my display settings and even put my working 1st in the chain to sleep.

I also put the xset command in the .profile file so that it puts my displays to sleep on login.

Hope this is fixed in the 20.04 version.

I'm on a P2000 Quadro card with four U2515Hc monitors. Your card may be too new.

Hope this helps, I can't comment yet.